# Setup celery periodic task

Tags: python, flask, celery

How do I set up a periodic task with Celerybeat and Flask that queries a database every hour?

The environment looks like this:

```
/
|-app
  |-__init__.py
  |-jobs
    |-task.py
|-celery-beat.sh
|-celery-worker.sh
|-manage.py
```

I currently have a query function called `run_query()` located in `task.py`

I want the scheduler to kick in once the application initiates so I have the following lines in my `/app/__init__.py` folder:

```py
celery = Celery()

@celery.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
  sender.add_periodic_task(1, app.jobs.task.run_query())
```

(For simplicity's sake, I've set it up so that **if** it runs, it will run every minute. No such luck yet.)

When I launch the `celery-worker.sh` it recognizes my function under the `[tasks]` heading. But the **scheduled** function never runs. I can manually force the function to run by issuing the following at the command prompt:

```
>> from app.jobs import task
>> task.run_query.delay()
```

**EDIT**: Added celerybeat.sh

As a follow up: If the database is accessed through a flask context, during my asynch function call is it wise to create a new flask context to access the database? Use the existing flask context? Or forget contexts altogether and just initiate a connection to the database? My worry is that if I just initiate a new connection it may interfere with the existing context's connection?

Comment: You need to run scheduler service also. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler. **celery beat** is a scheduler; It kicks off tasks at regular intervals, that are then executed by available worker nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score 5):

To run periodic tasks you need some kind of schduler (Eg. celery beat).

> **celery beat** is a scheduler; It kicks off tasks at regular intervals, that are then executed by available worker nodes in the
>   cluster.
>
> You have to ensure only a single scheduler is running for a schedule
>   at a time, otherwise you’d end up with duplicate tasks. Using a
>   centralized approach means the schedule doesn’t have to be
>   synchronized, and the service can operate without using locks.

Reference: [periodic-tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#introduction)

You can invoke scheduler with command,

```
$ celery -A proj beat #different process from your worker
```

> You can also embed beat inside the worker by enabling the workers -B
>   option, this is convenient if you’ll never run more than one worker
>   node, but it’s not commonly used and for that reason isn’t recommended
>   for production use Starting scheduler:

```
$ celery -A proj worker -B
```

Reference: [celery starting scheduler](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler)